# Disable Console text-wrapping from within a program

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, command-prompt

I have used pyinstaller to compile my program into a standalone .exe. 
The print functions my program uses requires there not to be any text wrapping when window size is too small (as this can cause some text to linger). I know there is a way to disable text wrapping from the properties menu in command prompt, but I was wondering if I could change this setting automatically from within the program.

Comment: It really depends on the terminal emulator program you are using. Different terminals may have escape codes that can be emitted to them, changing their behavior, possibly including the truncating behavior you want. A quick scan of the Windows cmd.exe temoinal documentation, however, does not lead me to think that this terminal supports such a capability.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance @AmitaiIrron . Wish it was possible.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron, cmd.exe is a shell that uses a console, just like any application that uses a console/terminal, and no different in that regard from other shells such as bash. A console session (i.e. the console function-based and virtual-terminal APIs) and default user interface is hosted by conhost.exe, with I/O implemented by the condrv.sys kernel driver. Windows 10 also has a new "Windows Terminal", which uses an open-sourced version of conhost.exe that's renamed "openconsole.exe" for the console session (condrv.sys is still used for console I/O files) and wt.exe for a modern terminal UI.

Comment: @ErykSun - all true (I guess. I did not check, but I take your word for it). Whati s your point, though? As I mentioned in several comments, most terminal emulators can handle escape sequence, including the Windows one. However, I did dig up some documentation and found the the VT100 terminal (an often emulated one) has an escape sequence that make it operate exactly like the OP wants (i.e., all the Python program needs to do is send some characters to stdout), while the windows teminal seem to lack support for such an escape sequence.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron, programming is engineering, which depends on using correct terminology and jargon. cmd.exe is a shell, not a terminal. It doesn't implement any UI, except for some UI related commands such as `color`, `title`, and `cls` that use the console API and only work when it's attached to a console. By writing a comment that says "cmd.exe terminal", you're cementing an incorrect understanding into however many hundreds or thousands of people read it, who will in turn write their own comments, and so on. It needs an immediate response that clarifies the correct usage. Nothing personal.

Comment: A bit late, and the correct answer isn't straight forward, but for reference, the windows console [api](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions), which is mostly mirrored through `win32con` and `win32console` packages.  You create a screen buffer and attach it to the console. Then you can set output mode with flags and write to the buffer rather than `print()`.  If you're happy to read through some code, you can mostly follow what it does by referring to msdn above.  See [example](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/blob/master/asciimatics/screen.py#L1273).

Comment: The above example, line 1313 is where this mode is set, i.e. `win_out.SetConsoleMode(out_mode & ~win32console.ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found your answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/73443/how-to-stop-the-terminal-from-wrapping-lines

Your script needs to run the command "tput rmam" to disable text wrapping. Then your script needs to be piped through "less -S". This probably needs to be wrapped in a sub-process that is embedded in your current process. Now your terminal will no longer wrap lines, you can still use the arrow keys to view more of lines that are too long.

Here is a mockup I wrote:

temp:

```
short line
long line long line long line long line long line long line long line long line long line long line long line long line long line 
short line
```

temp.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pexpect as pe

b = pe.spawn('bash')
b.sendline('tput rmam')
b.sendline('less temp -S')
b.interact() # Imbed in your current process.
```

Comment: I suspect the OP may be using Python on Windows (as he mentions .exe files). Additionally, I think the intent is for output from Python normal terminal output to be truncated. Using a spawned shell for this purpose is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Agreed, I did not catch the .exe part. However, it doesn't sound like the OP is interested in changing what python outputs, but rather changes the terminals behavior. I am assuming the OP may want to re-size the terminal while the program is running. Such thing probably requires submitting commands or changing settings files; I found such an example. Without embedding a subprocess in the current process, how else would you get python to change a terminal's behavior (thinking Linux here, obviously Windows can do hacky things with subprocesses).

Comment: Well, it looks like the VT100 terminal (a frequently emulated terminal) has a "disable line wrap" escape code, which would achieve the desired outcome simply by sending it at the start of the program. See [this link](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~kxc104/class/cmpen472/11f/hw/hw7/vt100ansi.htm).

Comment: Nice reference. I have used some of these before. Unfortunately, it seems the line wrapping does not work with Ubuntu mate terminal, I still get wrapped lines. The command "tput rmam" does disable line wrapping though.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron, with the addition of "?", i.e. `"\x1b[?7l"`, the VT command works in both GNOME Terminal in Linux and also in Windows Terminal (wt.exe) in Windows 10. For the regular console in Windows (conhost.exe), I tried enabling `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` (conhost.exe), but this VT command doesn't appear to be implemented yet. Maybe it will eventually get backported from Windows Terminal's openconsole.exe (the open-source fork of conhost.exe).

Comment: Works for me. Why is the "?" required?

Comment: @BobbyOcean, refer to [CSI sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences). Using the parameter "?7" instead of just "7" indicates a private sequence, for use by terminal manufacturers for their own custom sequences. The fact that this "7l" CSI sequence is said to "vary depending on the implementation" suggests that it's a private sequence.